# Find array of coprime integers whose average is maximized

Tags: algorithms, primes, modular-arithmetic

I am creating a class to store large integers in a [residue number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_number_system). I want each "integer" to be 4-12GB in size and be comprised of 64-bit moduli. These moduli must be pairwise coprime to each other. However, in order to maximize the maximum integer I can store, I want the average moduli to be at its greatest. I can not find or come up with an algorithm to do this in a reasonable amount of time. **It's very important that this average is close to maximized.**

I was thinking of using a segmented-sieve like algorithm where I start with $2^{64}-1$, find it's prime factors, then mark them all off of my sieve. I then decrement by $1$ and do the same for $2^{64}-2$ if it has not been marked off. I repeat this until I get however many I need.

I don't think this algorithm will work because if I choose to use some integer $n$, there may be other integers less than $n$ that would "use $n$'s factors more efficiently."

If it helps, I have a lookup table of all 32-bit primes.

Does anyone have some insight on this problem?

Comment: I would just take the $k$ largest primes in your range, for an appropriate $k$.

Comment: How close should it be? @YuvalFilmus's suggestion will differ from the optimum in a something like 10th significant digit.

Comment: I am looking for something closer because I need multiple gigabytes worth of these primes and I will be storing multiple of these RNS integers. In addition, the computation that I am doing with these large integers is very tightly timed.

Comment: (Use @Dmitry if you want to reply to me, this way I’ll get a notification). I don’t understand your argumentation: what you mention is not related to approximation at all.